# Java Selenium - ExpectedCopnditions Presence Passes but Visibility Fails

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I don't get it.. I have been searching for answers for 2 days now and I cannot find a single solution around this issue.

The code looks like this (within try catch block):

```
Presence = new WebDriverWait(Driver, custTimeout);
Presence.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(ElementXpath)));
```

Separate try catch block:

```
Visisble = new WebDriverWait(Driver, custTimeout);
Visisble.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(ElementXpath)));
```

This also shows as FALSE:

```
foundElement.isDisplayed();
```

AND this fails:

```
Clickable = new WebDriverWait(Driver, custTimeout);
Clickable.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(ElementXpath)));
```

Now, how/why does PRESENCE pass and VISIBILITY fails when the element IS visible on screen and CAN be clicked if I do this:

```
ElementToClick.get(0).click();
```

So basically, the element IS visible and the element IS interactable but yet the "check if visible" is failing with exception.

Seeing that the check for "visibility" basically looks for the height and width of the element, I decided to check this manually too by:

```
ElementToClick.getAttribute("height");
ElementToClick.getAttribute("width");
```

Both values are 0 (but I can see the element on the screen).

***Edit:***

So how can I go about identifying the element to be visible or not if these standard methods don't work?

Current Element Properties:

[image]

Checked these posts already:

[Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920201/expected-condition-failed-waiting-for-visibility-of-element-located-by-by-xpath/44921708)

[Selenium webdriver problem with: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by(..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353370/selenium-webdriver-problem-with-expected-condition-failed-waiting-for-visibili)

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/24459/selenium-webdriver-tests-sometimes-doesnt-find-elements

[Selenium: How selenium identifies elements visible or not? Is is possible that it is loaded in DOM but not rendered on UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i)

[isDisplayed() vs isVisible() in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380119/isdisplayed-vs-isvisible-in-selenium)

Comment: Interesting. Did you try this already?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038920/visibilityofelementlocated-vs-presenceofelementlocated

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I didn't specifically check that post, but I am currently using presence of element..

Answer (score 1):

### presenceOfElementLocated()

[`presenceOfElementLocated()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By)) is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.

```
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> presenceOfElementLocated​(By locator)

Parameters:
locator - used to find the element
Returns:
the WebElement once it is located
```

---

### visibilityOfElementLocated()

[`visibilityOfElementLocated()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By)) is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

```
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> visibilityOfElementLocated​(By locator)

Parameters:
locator - used to find the element
Returns:
the WebElement once it is located and visible
```

---

### Element displayedness

This implementation of `isDisplayed()` is inline with the specification with in the [WebDriver Level 2 W3C Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-displayedness) which mentions that:

> The recommended approach which will give a simplified approximation of
> an element's visibility, but please note that it relies only on
> tree-traversal, and only covers a subset of visibility checks.
>
> The visibility of an element is guided by what is perceptually visible
> to the human eye. In this context, an element’s displayedness does not
> relate to the
> [visibility](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-visibility) or
> [display](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-display) style
> properties.
>
> The approach recommended to implementors to ascertain an element’s
> visibility was originally developed by the Selenium project, and is
> based on crude approximations about an element's nature and
> relationship in the tree. An element is in general to be considered
> visible if any part of it is drawn on the canvas within the boundaries
> of the viewport.
>
> The element displayed algorithm is a boolean state where true
> signifies that the element is displayed and false signifies that the
> element is not displayed. To compute the state on element, invoke the
> **`Call(bot.dom.isShown, null, element)`**. If doing so does not produce an error, return the return value from this function call.
> Otherwise return an error with error code unknown error.

This function is typically exposed to GET requests with a URI Template of:

```
/session/{session id}/element/{element id}/displayed.
```

---

### Conclusion

An element perceptually visible to the human eye may can be rendered invisible by:

- Setting the CSS `visibility` property to **`hidden`**
- Setting the `display` property to **`none`**

for the element itself or one if its ancestors.

Comment: Thank you for the info.. Just wondering if you perhaps have a solution to the issue? As in how I can identify if an element is visible when the prescribed methods don't seem to do the job..

Comment: @EitelDagnin It would be injustice to speculate what exactly went wrong unless we know your proper usecase along with the text based HTML, code trials and error stacktace.

Comment: Thank you again for the quick reply. If I were to provide the identification properties of the element, would that be of any help in identifying a possible solution?

Comment: @EitelDagnin I didn't get your question. In short `presenceOfElementLocated()` and `visibilityOfElementLocated()` validated two different stages of an element.

Comment: Yes, I understand the various methods I listed in my question do different things, the question was more about how can I test if an element is indeed visible on the page if  the methods I provided don't work.. I need a way of identifying that the element is visible, that's what the issue is.. I do apologize, I was not specific in the post that I am looking for that as a solution, so I have updated the question.