# Difference between ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated() and ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I have two questions:

1)What is the difference between *ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated()* and *ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated()*? I am asking in context of visible and presence?what does here *visible* and *presence* means? does visible means visible in maximized browser window?

2)What if I use ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated() and minimize the browser? Will it give TimeoutException?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement)

> **visibilityOfElementLocated:**
>
> public static ExpectedCondition
> visibilityOfElementLocated​(By locator) An expectation for checking
> that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible.
> Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a
> height and width that is greater than 0. Parameters: locator - used to
> find the element Returns: the WebElement once it is located and
> visible
>
> **presenceOfElementLocated**:
>
> public static ExpectedCondition
> presenceOfElementLocated​(By locator) An expectation for checking that
> an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily
> mean that the element is visible. Parameters: locator - used to find
> the element Returns: the WebElement once it is located

**in visibility it checks for display property and also the rendered rectangle size of the image**

**In present it just check if the element is present in the DOM,**

### Example a tooltip text that gets displayed only when we hover over it , do the element is present always but visible only when we hover over it

Answer (score 0):

### presenceOfElementLocated()

[presenceOfElementLocated()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By)) is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. It is defines as:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> presenceOfElementLocated​(By locator)
An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.

Parameters:
locator - used to find the element

Returns:
the WebElement once it is located
```

So presenceOfElementLocated doesn't confirms the element is **visible** with in the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes). This phenomenon can be observed with [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) having:

- *CSS* `visibility` property set as **`hidden`**. As an example:

  ```
  h2.b {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  ```
- *style* attribute is set as **`"display: none;"`**. An example:

  ```
  <select class="pretty-dropdown" id="alBrandsList" style="display: none;">
  ```

---

### visibilityOfElementLocated()

[visibilityOfElementLocated()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By)) is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. It is defined as:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> visibilityOfElementLocated​(By locator)
An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

Parameters:
locator - used to find the element

Returns:
the WebElement once it is located and visible
```

---

### visibilityOfElementLocated() with the browser minimized

Visibility/invisibility of the minimized browser is subjected to our naked eyes where as presenceOfElementLocated / visibilityOfElementLocated is subjective to [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491).

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [How to execute tests with selenium webdriver while browser is minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504503/how-to-execute-tests-with-selenium-webdriver-while-browser-is-minimized/52515176#52515176)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions on element [displayedness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65699674/java-selenium-expectedcopnditions-presence-passes-but-visibility-fails/65702948#65702948) in:

- [Selenium: How selenium identifies elements visible or not? Is is possible that it is loaded in DOM but not rendered on UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165)
- [Selenium: Check for the presence of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610553/selenium-check-for-the-presence-of-element/50621712#50621712)
- [Why do some elements exist but not interactable/displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57693634/why-do-some-elements-exist-but-not-interactable-displayed/57699893#57699893)